# bitnami install, Document root, windows machine

Tags: php, bitnami

just downloaded bitnami and executed install on my windows machine.

1. How do i open my php.info page? Localhost takes me to bitnami welcome page.(index.html)
2. Where is my Document root?
3. I am trying to follow along in Tuts Plus "Php Fundamentals" where Jeffrey Way is using MAMP. His htdocs file is empty after He downloaded MAMP and was setting it up. I understand Bitnami is not MAMP but they should be similar?

I love the frameworks you can Select to bitnami that come preinstalled which is why I went this route but something as simple as showing php.info should be a breeze but I need some guidance to opening php.info on my local machine in Bitnami.

thx

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here.

Your Document root is located at /apache2/htdocs. There you can place a simple php file called `example.php` with the following content

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and then you'll find your phpinfo at http://yoursite.com/example.php

You may find this documentation page useful:

https://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_AMP_Stacks

Comment: Can I also use index.php instead of example.php?. Where would I put my www.com? Or is that what you meant by http://yoursite.com/example.php?